# i keep getting Undefined index: name and Undefined index: email

Tags: php, html

this is my first form

```
<style>
    .wrap-form{
        width: 700px;
        min-height: 20px;
        background-color: lightblue;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>

<div class="wrap-form">
    <form method="post" action="advanced-form-send"></form>
     Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email">
    <a href="advanced-form-send.php"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></a>
</div>
```

And this is my form 2 where the data will send to

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];

    echo $name;
    echo $email;
?>
```

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how your form code should be, surrounding your submit button by `<a href="..."` is causing the form not to be submitted, at the place you're just telling the browser that when this button is clicked, take the user to the page advanced-form-search.php. What you should do is put the script name where the form should be submitted in the action of the `form` tag then just add a submit button. And don't forget to close your tags... you missed the `</form>`

```
<div><?php if(isset($_GET['err'])){ if($_GET['err']==1){ echo 'You didn\'t fill in your name'; } elseif($_GET['err']==2){ echo 'You didn\'t fill in a correct email address';}}?></div>
<div class="wrap-form">
    <form method="post" action="advanced-form-send.php">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email">
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Here's the PHP code to send an email:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty(trim($_POST['name']))){
         $name = $_POST["name"];
    } else {
         header("Location: page_where_the_form_is.php?err=1");
         die()
    }
    if(isset($_POST['email']) && filter_var(trim($_POST['email']), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $email = $_POST["email"];
    }
    else {
         header("Location: page_where_the_form_is.php?err=2");
         die()
    }
    $subject='Form Submitted On The Website';
    $message="Name: {$name}\nEmail: {$email}";
    mail($to_email, $subject, $message);


 ?>
```

Comment: Notice that the answerer tacked on the file's extension, which is required.

Comment: but then when i click submit it does nothing dude

Comment: @code no way it does nothing! just copy paste the code as it is, maybe you missed something

Comment: shot buddy i see your error and corrected mine it works one time thanks a million

Comment: oh oh by the way why would some people use the isset function with the post eg:  if (isset($_POST["name"])) {
  echo "name";
         }

Comment: @code it is always better to test your post/get variables, to see if they're set or not, and in some cases if empty or not. That's the best practice.

Comment: so isset and empty is like the same? and tell me if i where to now send this values that my user types in to an email, would i change the action to : mailto:example@gmail.com???

Comment: isset and empty are different, `isset` tests if the variable is actually set, after the isset returns true, `empty` tests if it was set to something, or just an empty string. And no you don't use mailto:. I'll update my code

Comment: @CodeBird: how would i check on the first page if any values have been inserted by the user into the textboxes and if not display the errors on the same page as the first form??

Comment: You have to use javascript, which will check the form before it being submitted and if something is wrong it won't submit, search for how to validate form with javascript. But you can't only count on javascript as it may be turned off, so you should add stuff in PHP, I'll update my code, but that's the last time.

Answer (score 0):

You've wrapped your `<input type="submit" name="submit"...` button with an `<a href=...`. What this does is prevents your form from being submitted as a POST request, and instead gets linked to as a GET request.

git rid of the `<a href...`, and and change your `action=advanced-form-send` to `action="advanced-form-send.php"`.

Answer (score 0):

**You can improve your php code:**

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST["name"])) {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        echo $name;
    } else {
        echo 'Eror: Attribute "name" is missing!';
    }

    if (isset($_POST["email"])) {
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        echo $email;
    } else {
        echo 'Eror: Attribute "email" is missing!';
    }

 ?>
```

**And your form should be changed:**

```
<form method="post" action="advanced-form-send.php">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your variables. The other answers are about the form. This answer is about your handling of variables. PHP will throw a notice if you use a variable that haven't been set. By using isset() you can determine if the variable is set and then use it.

```
<?php

    $name = isset($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : '';
    $email = isset($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : '';

    echo $name;
    echo $email;


 ?>
```

Doing it this way ensures that you wont get a notice if one of your fields haven't been posted. If they have you will have the value in $name and $email. If not then the variables will be empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this,

```
<div class="wrap-form">
    <form method="post" action="advanced-form-send">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email">
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The submit button should be in the two "form" markups. Also the link is unnecessary because the input "submit" will send the form with the data to the page you set in the attribute "action" of the form markup.

```
<div class="wrap-form">
    <form method="post" action="advanced-form-send.php">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Youre missing an enctype ... you ALL forgot it. Shame above you!

```
<form method="post" action="advanced-form-send.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
```

Comment: your response could be right if it was an input file.

Comment: Oh. Well. Maybe i should start reading the whole code, i just jumped out when i saw enctype is missing. xD

Comment: yeah don't jump, and say shame on you to people before reading the question!

Comment: Calm down, that was meant as a joke ... why do you have to take everything offensive? :o